# Save open Mathematica Notebook from command line or second Notebook to avoid data loss

Tags: kernel, interface, remote-access, save

I was executing a long Mathematica Notebook over night. The Mathematica instance is running on a Linux workstation (in a vnc server session to be precise). Now I cannot access this session anymore, which means that I likely loose the output data which was produced during the run.
I can still login on the workstation as the same user and run Mathematica there. I know from the process list that Mathematica is still running, but I cannot access the GUI anymore. So, if there would be a remote control for Mathematica from command line or a second worksheet, which allows me to save the worksheet, I could prevent the data loss.
I already tried to run a second instance of Mathematica but it seems that I cannot even see the Kernels there.
Any ideas? It would save my day.

Comment: That's why I always write the results of my long calculations  to a file. `Export[...,"file.mx.gz"]` is your friend. Doesn't help you now, I know...

Comment: Oh, for next time, there is also `NotebookAutoSave`.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no good solution here.  I've been looking into accessing already running kernels on remote machines to examine and change their state a couple of years ago.  If you don't already have some setup to enable this, then I don't think it's worth spending any more effort.  Just re-run the calculation next time you can access the machine and make sure the results are saved at the end of the calculation using Export.

Comment: Oh, and beware of `.mx`! It's not cross platform or cross-version.  Never keep important data in `.mx`.  An cross-platform, cross-version alternative is to `Compress` your expressions and write the resulting string into a file.  I use `zimport[filename_] := Uncompress@Import[filename, "String"];
zexport[filename_, data_] := 
 Export[filename, Compress[data], "String"]`

Comment: Ok, guys thanks for the hints. What's your experience with the `NotebookAutoSave` feature? Is it stable? My experience with other software is that it may crash while saving, especially if the files are big. It can then leave the files in an inconsistent/partial state.

Comment: @Szabolcs What do you think, worth an answer or "requires specialist"?